# How do I add a class to preceding sibling?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML structure (snippet):

```
    <div id="mySearch" class="search_input">
        <form id="searchForm" method="get" action="../search.html">
            <div>
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search " class="search_textfield"
                    id="textToSearch" name="searchQuery" />
                <button type="submit" class="search_button">
                    <span>Search</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="tools hidden-print">
                <div data-tooltip-position="bottom" class=" breadcrumb ">
                    <ol xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="hidden-print">
                        <li>
                            <span class="home">
                                <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="title">
                                <a href="install-system.html">Installation</a>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="topicref">
                                <span class="title">
                                    <a href="setup.html"> Setup system </a>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'd like to add a class to the #mySearch depending on the div.breadcrumb text below it. For example, if the value of the second breadcrumb ('Installation') (Home > Installation > ...) and then add a class 'install' to the search div #mySearch.

Here's what I've put together but it's not working. I'm not sure how to select the second breadcrumb, so I just searched for the text "Installation".

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('.breadcrumb:contains("Installation")').length > 0) {
    $("#mySearch").addClass("install");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Someone posted a solution that I stated didn't work. Then the person then deleted the post. However, after working his solution for a while, I was able to get it to work!  So, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone posted a solution that I stated didn't work. Then the person then deleted the post. However, after working this solution for a while, I was able to get it to work!  So, thank you!

`$(document).ready(function () { // path: //div/ol/li/span/a
    var current_class=$.trim($('.breadcrumb > ol > li:eq(1) > span > a').text()).toLowerCase();
    current_class = current_class.replace(/\s+/g, '_'); // convert spaces to _
    console.log(current_class);
    $('#mySearch').addClass(current_class)
});`

I'm a novice when it comes to JS, so someone else might be able to come up with a more elegant solution, but this works for me.